# The influence of electric potential of a planet to a spaceship

Tags: electrostatics, electricity

How does the electric potential of a planet influence a spaceship? If a distant planet is at very high potential compared to Earth. A spaceship is sent from Earth to land on the planet. Is the mission dangerous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are implicitly assuming that the spacecraft is the only object around which can feel the influence of the charged potential. That's not true - if there is a somehow-got-electrically-charged planet (let us say negatively charged, due to electron excess), it would electromagnetically influence all charged entities (and some neutral ones too, due to induction). Please notice that the gravitational force on unit masses is much weaker in comparison to electrostatic force due to unit charges, so that can also mean a lot of transient damage, while this excess charge is not wiped off. Speaking of that, this electron-excess planet would attract the positively charged ingredients of [cosmic rays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_ray) (i.e. protons and $\alpha$ particles), so the electron excess can potentially be wiped off by these. The precise time it will take for the neutralization to occur shall depend on the particle flux as well as the amount of electron excess, but your hypothetical charged planet won't stay charged forever.

> Is the mission dangerous?

No, if you wait for long enough!

Comment: And please don't say, I have connected the planet to a battery which maintains this potential ... :P